# Proving a theorem in predicate logic without the use of metatheorems

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to prove: $$\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\forall x (\phi) \rightarrow \forall x (\psi))$$
and
$$\forall x \forall y (\phi) \rightarrow \forall y \forall x (\phi) $$

using the traditional axioms of predicate logic (and whatever standard theorems from propositional logic necessary):

1. $$\forall x (\phi(x)) \rightarrow \phi(y)$$
2. $$\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \forall x (\psi))$$

and generalization as the inference rule:
$$\vdash \phi \rightarrow \space \vdash \forall x(\phi) $$

Just to be explicit I am using the following axioms for propositional logic:
$$\phi \rightarrow ( \psi \rightarrow \phi )$$
$$(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta) ) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) $$
$$(\lnot\phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi) $$
and modus ponens as the inference rule.

I know how to prove these propositions using the deduction theorem, but I would like to prove them without invoking it (or any other metatheorem for that matter) .

I tried but I can't use generalization to conclude
$$ \psi \rightarrow \space  \forall x(\psi) $$
and use hypothetical syllogism (the closed form) to get to the proposition - that is:

I get
$$(\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \space \land \space \forall x (\phi)) \space \rightarrow \space (\phi \rightarrow \psi) $$
by 1. and some theorems of propositional logic,
also:
$$(\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \space \land \space \forall x (\phi) ) \space \rightarrow \space \phi  $$
so I conclude
$$(\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \space \land \space \forall x (\phi)) \rightarrow (\phi \land (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$$
that is:
$$(\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \space \land \space \forall x (\phi)) \rightarrow \psi$$

Is there a way to continue from here...or am I way off

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry - I should have thought more before posting this...guess I was tired and frustrated last night. Anyway:

$$(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \vdash \forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi) $$

if x is bounded in $$\phi$$ we get 
$$(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \vdash ( \phi \rightarrow \forall x ( \psi) ) $$
but x is bounded in the antecedent in the last line (of the post) from which the proposition follows